# Can't get value of excel formula by pandas read_excel except manually save the file again

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm using **xlsxwriter** to create my excel file **data.xlsx**. The file contain some cell with formula:

```
for example: =73-B2
```

Then I make a xhr query to read that **data.xlsx** by pandas (from django)

```
pd.read_excel('data.xlsx','sheet_name="dn")
```

However the first time read that file, value of the cell contains formula can't be get, except I manually open data.xlsx, save it.. then got the value.

I found [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722374/pandas-read-excel-values-not-formulas?rq=1) but there is not a solution

Comment: I think someone posted the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102674/how-can-i-see-the-formulas-of-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-pandas-python)
is this helping?

Comment: This is explained in the XlsxWriter docs and the FAQ: [Q. Why do my formulas show a zero result in some, non-Excel applications?](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/faq.html). Basically, XlsxWriter doesn't evaluate a formula or write the result (apart from a default result of 0). So you cannot create a formula with XlsxWriter and then read the result back out. You should either evaluate the formula you want in Python or use one of the Python modules that automates Excel like xlwings.

Comment: @nickthefreak thank you but isn't the answer i'm looking for

Comment: @jmcnamara thank you, I got it, so I try to evaluate values rather than the formula and It works