# Pandas read_excel skiprows on Capital IQ series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file. In row 1 (A:I) are text values, which I want to be the headers of my dataframe. In row 2 (A:I) are CIQRANGE functions which I want to be ignored when converting to dataframe. In rows 3:1425 are the values; column A has dates and columns B:I have numbers.

No matter how I structure read_excel I get an empty dataframe with 9 very odd and long text column names that I think represent the CIQRANGE functions in row 2. skiprows doesn't seem to have an effect.

What I think should work:

```py
priceHistory = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=0, skiprows=[1], sheetname=1)
```

Comment: Maybe share the original Excel file somehow? A bit hard to replicate what is wrong without the file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about `sheetname=1`? If you have one sheet this argument should be omitted, `None` or `0`.

> sheet_name : str, int, list, or None, default 0
>   Available cases:
>
> Defaults to 0: 1st sheet as a DataFrame

Comment: Yes, the first sheet is not what I want to be read; target information is on the second sheet.

Comment: Pelase see the comment above - hard to imagine what is wrong without the file. Looks like the values not computed before reading the file. See some clues here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722374/pandas-read-excel-values-not-formulas