When using pandas to read an excel file, any cells that use vlookup to another table are being read as NaN, is there a workaround?
While trying to read a .xlsx file to a dataframe in pandas (using both Python 3.9 and 3.12), any cells in the sheet that have a =VLOOKUP() formula in it, are read as NaN, this happens both locally and running inside an AWS Lambda. No errors are shown.
Nothing out of the ordinary, just a simple:
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=sheet)
An interesting fact is that if I just open that file with LibreOffice and save it as is and try to read it again the issue is resolved, the problem is that this file comes directly from a server to AWS and is used in a few processes, there's no manual intervention to just open and save it with LibreOffice.
I've got no idea as to why opening the files with LibreOffice, saving without any changes and reading it again, solves the issue. So any suggestions?

Drop down into openpyxl and see if it works. Then you can build your dataframe

@sammywemmy doing that I get the formula instead of the value, the cells are read as: =VLOOKUP(content), if I use load_workbook and pass data_only = True I get none instead of the formulas, but neither returns the values shown in the cell.

Hmmmm I am out of ideas

Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41722374/12846804

So this was an issue due to Excel saving foreign language sheets with different formulas apparently, in my case I had to load all sheets and remake the VLOOKUP myself using different dataframes and joining data.
So if you have a Portuguese Excel file, it may store the function as PROCV instead of the VLOOKUP that one would expect, this broke pandas basically when loading the df with all engines, but for whatever reason opening the file with LibreOffice just stored the formulas in English again.
